# There must be KBD option in the editor

Tags: feature-request

A lot of Questions and answers in elementary require the use of keyboard shortcuts, but there is no GUI option in the markdown editor to make selected text a Keyboard shortcut.

This makes new users use 'parentheses' or `code` to highlight the shortcuts
rather than using <kbd>kbd</kbd>.

It might be great if this was a GUI Option.

Answer (score 5):

We don't really have control over that as far as I know. See this question on StackExchange meta: [Key equivalent for <kbd></kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102841/key-equivalent-for-kbd-kbd)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to add support for this feature to your browser then I'd suggest installing this:

https://stackapps.com/q/3341/7653

It's a userscript that addons **kbd** buttons to the editor.